# How to find host of docker-compose running in gitlab

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using docker-compose to run integration tests.  The integration tests take the host (or ip) of the webservice container (running in docker-compose)in order to test the application.  Hence,  need to find the host the container is running on (when running docker-compose in gitlab ci).  When running locally, I use "localhost", when running plain docker in gitlab ci, I use "docker", but these do not work when running docker compose.  I have a few thoughts, can you please offer advice on which is preferable, or provide other options:
1 - assigning a network in docker-compose so that the application gets a static ip, and I connect to that
2 - use docker inspect to dynamically find the ip of the service running
3 - find a static host (such as "docker-compose") and use this.

Please advise,
Connor

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest assigning a network in your docker-compose file and have a static ip for all your services.